# Bootstrap CheckBox Into TabPanel Tab Doesn't Check/Uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that checkboxes that are inside tab-panel tabs doesn't check.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/696/)

HTML Code here:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#home">
            <div style="margin: 0;" class="checkbox">
                <label style="float: left;">
                    <input style="display: inline-block;" type="checkbox" id="product" value="home" />
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">Home</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#profiles">
            <div style="margin: 0;" class="checkbox">
                <label style="float: left;">
                    <input style="display: inline-block;" type="checkbox" id="product" value="profiles" />
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">Profiles</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#messages">
            <div style="margin: 0;" class="checkbox">
                <label style="float: left;">
                    <input style="display: inline-block;" type="checkbox" id="product" value="messages" />
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">Messages</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas? How can I make those checkboxes do the check and uncheck function?

Comment: why there is same id for each checkbox ?

Comment: Because this is only an example. Changing the id to unique doesn't give me the needed result.

Comment: Bunga : check my answer.
and yes id should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are preventing it for clicking. Removing  `e.preventDefault()` would solve the problem

Comment: only removing that line , doesn't uncheck your checkboxs when you move to other tabs.

Answer (score 2):

youe jquery would be

```
$('#myTab li').click(function (e) {
 // e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('a').tab('show');
 // $(this).tab('show');
     $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','');
     $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','checked');

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/K9LpL/699/)

Comment: notice a bug in chrome, after initialisation you can switch between tabs when clicking direct on the checkbox but the checkbox doesn't get active, issue is solved when clicking first time on the tab title and not the checkbox to switch between tabs

Comment: @toms: this is actually because i have written this code on click event of anchor tag "<a>". if you want it on checkbox then you can do that.
wait i'll update my answer.